# Active Directory (LDAP) - Check account locked out / Password expired

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Currently I authenticate users against some AD using the following code:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, username, pwd);

try
{
    // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
    Object obj = entry.NativeObject;

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + username + ")" };
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
    if (result == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Update the new path to the user in the directory
    _path = result.Path;
    _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
}
```

This works perfectly for validating a password against a username.

The problem comes in that a generic errors is always returned "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." when authentication fails.

However authentication might also fail when an account is locked out.

How would I know if it is failing because of it being locked out?

I've come across articles saying you can use:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(entry.InvokeGet("IsAccountLocked"))
```

or do something like explained [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Determining_Account_Lockout)

The problem is, whenever you try to access any property on the DirectoryEntry, the same error would be thrown.

Any other suggestion of how to get to the actual reason that authentication failed?  (account locked out / password expired / etc.)

The AD I connect to might not neccesarily be a windows server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A little late but I'll throw this out there.

If you want to REALLY be able to determine the specific reason that an account is failing authentication (there are many more reasons other than wrong password, expired, lockout, etc.), you can use the windows API LogonUser.  Don't be intimidated by it - it is easier than it looks.  You simply call LogonUser, and if it fails you look at the Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() which will give you a return code that indicates the (very) specific reason that the logon failed.

However, you're not going to be able to call this in the context of the user you're authenticating; you're going to need a priveleged account - I believe the requirement is SE_TCB_NAME (aka SeTcbPrivilege) - a user account that has the right to 'Act as part of the operating system'.

```
//Your new authenticate code snippet:
        try
        {
            if (!LogonUser(user, domain, pass, LogonTypes.Network, LogonProviders.Default, out token))
            {
                errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                success = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(token);    
        }            
        success = true;
```

if it fails, you get one of the return codes (there are more that you can look up, but these are the important ones:

```
 //See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155012
    const int ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE = 1907;
    const int ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE = 1326;
    const int ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION = 1327;
    const int ERROR_ACCOUNT_DISABLED = 1331;
    const int ERROR_INVALID_LOGON_HOURS = 1328;
    const int ERROR_NO_LOGON_SERVERS = 1311;
    const int ERROR_INVALID_WORKSTATION = 1329;
    const int ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT = 1909;      //It gives this error if the account is locked, REGARDLESS OF WHETHER VALID CREDENTIALS WERE PROVIDED!!!
    const int ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXPIRED = 1793;
    const int ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 1330;
```

The rest is just copy/paste to get the DLLImports and values to pass in

```
  //here are enums
    enum LogonTypes : uint
        {
            Interactive = 2,
            Network =3,
            Batch = 4,
            Service = 5,
            Unlock = 7,
            NetworkCleartext = 8,
            NewCredentials = 9
        }
        enum LogonProviders : uint
        {
            Default = 0, // default for platform (use this!)
            WinNT35,     // sends smoke signals to authority
            WinNT40,     // uses NTLM
            WinNT50      // negotiates Kerb or NTLM
        }

//Paste these DLLImports

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool LogonUser(
         string principal,
         string authority,
         string password,
         LogonTypes logonType,
         LogonProviders logonProvider,
         out IntPtr token);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have found testing against a Windows 2008 AD Server that for expired but valid passwords, the result will be `ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE`, but if the password is expired and the password provided is invalid, the result will be `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE`.

Comment: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16796531/1230982) if you can't use LogonUser and need an LDAP solution.

Answer (score 9):

I know this answer is a few years late, but we just ran into the same situation as the original poster. Unfortunately, in our environment, we can't use LogonUser -- we needed a pure LDAP solution. It turns out there is a way to get the extended error code from a bind operation. It's a bit ugly, but it works:

```
catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException exc)
{
    if((uint)exc.ExtendedError == 0x80090308)
    {
        LDAPErrors errCode = 0;

        try
        {
            // Unfortunately, the only place to get the LDAP bind error code is in the "data" field of the 
            // extended error message, which is in this format:
            // 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09030B, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v893
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exc.ExtendedErrorMessage))
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(exc.ExtendedErrorMessage, @" data (?<errCode>[0-9A-Fa-f]+),");
                if(match.Success)
                {
                    string errCodeHex = match.Groups["errCode"].Value;
                    errCode = (LDAPErrors)Convert.ToInt32(errCodeHex, fromBase: 16);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

        switch(errCode)
        {
            case LDAPErrors.ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
            case LDAPErrors.ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE:
                throw new Exception("Your password has expired and must be changed.");

            // Add any other special error handling here (account disabled, locked out, etc...).
        }
    }

    // If the extended error handling doesn't work out, just throw the original exception.
    throw;
}
```

And you'll need definitions for the error codes (there are a lot more of these at http://www.lifeasbob.com/code/errorcodes.aspx):

```
private enum LDAPErrors
{
    ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD = 0x56,
    ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION = 0x52D,
    ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE = 0x52e,
    ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION = 0x52f,
    ERROR_INVALID_LOGON_HOURS = 0x530,
    ERROR_INVALID_WORKSTATION = 0x531,
    ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x532,
    ERROR_ACCOUNT_DISABLED = 0x533,
    ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXPIRED = 0x701,
    ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE = 0x773,
    ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT = 0x775,
    ERROR_ENTRY_EXISTS = 0x2071,
}
```

I couldn't find this information anywhere else -- everyone just says you should use LogonUser. If there's a better solution, I'd love to hear it. If not, I hope this helps other people who can't call LogonUser.

Comment: In addition to your link I found this MS reference handy: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/155012

Comment: even if the account is locked, I still get only COMException and not DirectoryServicesCOMException. So this method does not work.

Answer (score 4):

The "password expires" check is relatively easy - at least on Windows (not sure how other systems handle this): when the Int64 value of "pwdLastSet" is 0, then the user will have to change his (or her) password at next logon. The easiest way to check this is include this property in your DirectorySearcher:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
      { Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + username + ")" };
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");

SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
if (result == null)
{
    return false;
}

Int64 pwdLastSetValue = (Int64)result.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];
```

As for the "account is locked out" check - this seems easy at first, but isn't.... The "UF_Lockout" flag on "userAccountControl" doesn't do its job reliably.

Beginning with Windows 2003 AD, there's a new computed attribute which you can check for: `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed`.

Given a DirectoryEntry `user`, you can do:

```
string attribName = "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed";
user.RefreshCache(new string[] { attribName });

const int UF_LOCKOUT = 0x0010;

int userFlags = (int)user.Properties[attribName].Value;

if(userFlags & UF_LOCKOUT == UF_LOCKOUT) 
{
   // if this is the case, the account is locked out
}
```

If you can use .NET 3.5, things have gotten a lot easier - check out the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) on how to deal with users and groups in .NET 3.5 using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. E.g. you now do have a property `IsAccountLockedOut` on the UserPrincipal class which reliably tells you whether or not an account is locked out.

Hope this helps!

Marc

Comment: Thanks marc ... will try it out.  Doesn't the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in .NET 3.5 limit me to windows active directories though?  Or does it still apply the same LDAP prinicipals?

Comment: Ah sorry - yes, S.DS.AM is Active Directory specific, sorry. But there's also a "low-level" LDAP library in namespace System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, since .NET 2.0 (I believe)

Comment: Hi Marc, I tried out the suggestions, but keep running into the same issue. I can't even apply a DirectorySearcher if I pass the username/pwd into the DirectoryEntry constructor, as authentication will fail if account is locked out.  If I don't pass it through I can do a search, but don't get to any of the mention properties. "pwdLastSet" is not there and user.Properties is always empty. Guess I'll have to place this on ice for a while.

Comment: @jabezz: well, the user that is locked out of course cannot log in and check his status - you'll have to have an admin log in and check that user's account.

Comment: @marc : you are correct, however the authentication done in code, might cause the account to lock out. Thus it should first show the user that login was unsuccessful because of an invalid password, then when he tries to log in again, show him a message that his account has been locked out and he should contact an administrator. Otherwise he will just keep trying to log in if we just say the password is invalid.

Comment: @jabezz: I see and understand what you're trying to do - but as far as I can recall, there's no way to find that out. If the user is locked out, he can't log in to check if he's locked out :-( and the error message from the failed login isn't specific as to WHY he can't log in (wrong password or account locked out). You would have to have an admin console to log in to find out whether the user is indeed locked out or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the AD LDAP attributes that change for a user when a password is locked out (first value) versus when a password is not locked out (second value). `badPwdCount` and `lockoutTime` are obviously the most relevant. I'm not sure whether uSNChanged and whenChanged must be updated manually or not.

`$ diff LockedOut.ldif NotLockedOut.ldif`:

```
< badPwdCount: 3
> badPwdCount: 0

< lockoutTime: 129144318210315776
> lockoutTime: 0

< uSNChanged: 8064871
> uSNChanged: 8065084

< whenChanged: 20100330141028.0Z
> whenChanged: 20100330141932.0Z
```